# C# Encrypt only files under x size

Tags: c#

It's a simple question seeking a simple answer

How can I **encrypt** only the files that are under 1 GB of size?

I call my encrypt method with this code

```
foreach(string file in files)
{
    EncryptFile(file, password);
}
```

Comment: _"How can I encrypt only the files that are under 1 GB of size?"_ -- um, look at the size first and don't encrypt the file if it's smaller than your minimum? What have you tried? Your question is way too broad, and shows no evidence whatsoever that you've tried _anything_.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer.

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
    if(File.Exists(file) && new FileInfo(file).Length < 1073741824) //1073741824 = 1GB
    {
        EncryptFile(file, password);
    }
}
```

The explanation.

Check that the file exists, next use the [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class to get the [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx) of the file (size) in bytes. Next check to ensure its less than 1GB *1073741824* bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx). So try this:

```
foreach(string file in files)
{
    var length = new System.IO.FileInfo(file).Length;
    if (length < 1073741824)
        EncryptFile(file, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
foreach(string file in files)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
    if (fi.Length < 1073741824)
        EncryptFile(file, password);
}
```